# How to make thumbs 70% bigger on hover with jQuery

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I want jQuery colorbox to open the picture on mouse hover and close on mouseout. 
Can you advice how I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could get you started...

#### HTML

```
<img src="a.jpg" alt="b" />
```

#### jQuery

```
$('img').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ width: '170%' }, 500);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ width: '100%' }, 500);
});
```

Comment: i am trying on http://www.rus-inter.ru/gallery.php?prod_id=69 with $('.b21').hover(... and it's not working ((((

Comment: what I need just small thumbs to get bigger on hover and outstand a little bit not pushing other images to anywhere... the scripts for zooming I found all needs fixed sizes. ((

Comment: you need to make it position: absolute

Comment: and you probably want it to stay in the same position so you need to change margin-left/top to -half the new width/height

Answer (score 0):

i would do something like this:

```
 $(function(){
  function fatOnHover($elements, zoomSize, animationSpeed){
  $elements.each(function(i){
     var $wrap, height, width, bigWidth, bigHeight, $that = $(this);
     height = $that.height();
     width = $that.width();
     bigWidth = (width / 100) * zoomSize;
     bigHeight = (height / 100) * zoomSize;
      $wrap = "<div style='z-index: " + (10000-i) +";width: " + width + "px; height: " + height + "px; position: relative; float: left'></div>",
      $that.data({"width": width, "height": height, "bigWidth": bigWidth, "bigHeight": bigHeight})
          .wrap($wrap)
   }).hover(
     function(){
        var $that = $(this);
        $that.stop().animate({"width": $that.data("bigWidth"), "height": $that.data("bigHeight")}, animationSpeed)
     },
     function(){
        var $that = $(this);
        $that.stop().animate({"width": $that.data("width"), "height": $that.data("height")}, animationSpeed)
     }
  ).css("position", "absolute")
   }


fatOnHover($('img'), 120, 300)
})
```

you can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/GHuNF/1/

Comment: I have made my version. but I have problems with the position of  images and UL tag width. Any idea what will fix it?  link http://www.rus-inter.ru/gallery.php?prod_id=57